# Problem calling a public function that references a private function in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm fairly new to typescript. In javascript, I would sometimes expose functions in a module through a single object (e.g. "services"). I'm trying to do the same thing in typescript but am having trouble. Here is my simplified code:

```js
class Tester {
  public publicField = "public field";
  private privateField = "private field";

  public services() {
    return {
        service1: this.getThePrivateField
    };
  }

  public getThePublicField() {
    return this.publicField;
  }

  private getThePrivateField() {
    console.log("reached getThePrivateField");
    return this.privateField;
  }

}

const t = new Tester();
console.log(t.services().service1()); // returns undefined but WHY?
```

When I call t.services().service1(), I know the code gets inside the getThePrivateField function as I've put a console.log there. So why is the response undefined?

Comment: By copying a method into a new object the method will use that object as its `this` context when you call it.  That object has no `privateField` property, so you get `undefined`.  If you want to call a method on one object but have its `this` context be a different object, you need to re-bind the method: `return {service1: this.getThePrivateField.bind(this)};` should fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is plain old javascript `this` confusion. To make what you're trying to achieve work you would need to call `t.services().service1.bind(t)()`.

This arises from the fact that, in the function `t.services().service1`, `this` is actually the object you're returning from `services()`, which doesn't have any `privateField` key.